# Запрет одновременного запуска двух и более Plyr-плееров

Tags: javascript, html, видео, online-video

Приветствую уважаемых знатоков. Вопрос таков: может кому приходилось в жизни сталкиваться с plyr плеером для видео и человек подскажет мне, как запретить одновременный запуск нескольких видео? По плану при запуске нового видео, прошлое должно становиться на паузу либо же полностью останавливаться. Пока это весь код, но он только инициализирует каждый плеер. Параметр load, в window.addEventListener, работает с vimeo видео успешно, а с ютубовским - увы никак.
К сожалению, вставленный код вообще работать не хочет, посему оставляю ссылку на кодпен.
https://codepen.io/Metalspell/pen/PLdwRW

```js
const players = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".player"));

  players.map(
    player =>
      new Plyr(player, {
        debug: true,
        autoplay: false,
      })
  );
  
  players.forEach(function(player) {
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      player.pause();
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.4.8/plyr.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.4.8/plyr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='player' data-plyr-provider="youtube" data-plyr-embed-id="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1Y8Z44P8qI"></div>
<br>
<div class='player' data-plyr-provider="youtube" data-plyr-embed-id="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBE1_VWcpCw"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено.

```js
const players = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.player')).map(player => new Plyr(player));
players.forEach(function(instance,index) {
  instance.on('play',function(){
    players.forEach(function(instance1,index1){
      if(instance != instance1){
        instance1.pause();
      }
    });
  });
});
```